# Compare and count in two arrays not in same order - Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting

I need to count how many of the same digits are in the code vs. guess.

If code = [1, 2, 5, 6] and guess = [4, 1, 3, 2], it should return 2.

I can't directly change the parameter arrays, so I first created new arrays, sorted, then looped through to find how many are the same in both. The issue is that it returns 4 no matter what.

```
public static int digits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
        int[] sortedCode = new int[code.length];
        int[] sortedGuess = new int[guess.length];
        int digits = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
            sortedCode[i] = code[i];
            sortedGuess[i] = guess[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(sortedCode);
        Arrays.sort(sortedGuess);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
            if (sortedGuess[i] == sortedCode[i]) {
                digits++;
            }
        }
        return digits;
```

Comment: In your first loop you set the contents of both `sortedGuess` and `sortedCode` to the contents of `code`.

Comment: But imagine you fix that, and sortedGuess is 1234 while sorted code is 2345. Will you get the right answer?

Comment: @tgdavies Oops, fixed, thank you! And no, it's still wrong. If it's 4, it returns 4, but if it's 3, 2, 1, it mostly returns 0. Sometimes it returns something else wrong, but I can't figure out a pattern.

Comment: you are comparing index to index when you should compare index to every index in the array

Comment: @Icarus I just realized sortedGuess[i] == sortedCode[I] is the error. How do I compare index to every index in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Icarus mentioned in the comments, "you're comparing index to index when you should compare index to every index".

```java
public static int getCorrectDigits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
        int correctDigits = 0;

        if (code.length != guess.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different lengths");
        }

        for (int x = 0; x<code.length; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y<guess.length; y++){
                if (code[x] == guess[y]){
                    correctDigits++;
                }
            }
        }

        return correctDigits;
    }
```

You can also convert the traditional `for` loop to an enhanced `for` loop.

```java
    for (int j : code) {
            for (int i : guess) {
                if (j == i) {
                    correctDigits++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also, see Enhanced ```for``` loop.

Comment: Try it with guess 1111 and code 1234. What answer do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for Adding.
@cymru_yesac please add a ```break``` after ```correctDigits++```.
Does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Nili why don't you write a few basic unit tests for your code?

Comment: @tgdavies I have a unit test file. Break fixes duplicates in the guess, but it still fails if there are duplicates in the code

Comment: @cymru_yesac You have to write a code to fix the duplicates.

Comment: This got it to work, not sure if formatting will post it right, but thank you so much for all of your help! `for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j < code.length; j++) { if (code[i] == code[j] && code[i] != guess[j]) { correctDigits--; } } }`

Comment: @cymru_yesac Sorry, but the code you posted doesn't work for me. 
According to your question, you want to know how many guesses are correct, right?
Like a lottery why would anyone input a duplicate number?
The ```break``` statement is doing the job.

If you want to remove the duplicates or manipulate your array, I recommend you use ```Arraylist```.  Because manipulating traditional arrays is a headache.

Comment: @Nili It's a modified version of Mastermind and a lot of the test cases have duplicate digits in the code. What I posted above works if both code and guess duplicates are in the same place, but fails if they're in the wrong place